# Retrieve the Following Occurrence of the String 'PWD' Once the Given String is Located

Tags: solaris, string, posix, pattern-matching, file-search

Below is my sample test.log file

```
export SQRDIR=/v/orahome/Middleware/Oracle/bin64


 
export OID=ap0092

export PWD=pass1

export FDPWD=pass1

export AP0085_PWD=pass1

export SVR=AFFPROD

export TWO_TASK=db01

 

export EF_OID=AP0093

export EF_PWD=pass2

 

export CCC_PER_OID=CCC_JAS

export CCC_PER_PWD=pass3

 

export CAN_PER_OID=CAN_JAS

export CAN_PER_PWD=pass4

 

###################################################
```

The user inputs `ap0092`. Upon this input, I need to search for the first occurrence of PWD after the first occurrence of the search string i.e. `=ap0092`

Thus, the desired output will be `pass1`

Likewise, for `CCC_JAS` the desired output will be `pass3`

I need the solution for Solaris OS.

I was doing `grep -A 1` [for non-Solaris] to get the next line but do not know how to search if the desired line may not be the very next line.

Please note: There may be multiple lines or Whiteline between `export OID=ap0092` and

`export PWD=pass1`

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I was doing grep -A 1 [for non-solaris] to get the next line but do not know how to search if the desired line may not be the very next line.

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
oid="${1?No OID specified}"
file=/path/to/your/file.log

die() {
  printf>&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}

password=$(
  OID=$oid perl -ne '
    if (/^export (\w+_)?OID=(.*)$/) {
      $prefix = $1 if $right_oid = $2 eq $ENV{OID};
    } elsif ($right_oid && /^export ${prefix}PWD=(.*)$/) {
      print "$1\n"; $found = 1; exit
    }
    END {exit !$found}' < "$file"
) || die "No password found for $oid"

printf '%s\n' "The password for $oid is $password"
```

If on Solaris 10 or older, replace `#! /bin/sh` with `#! /usr/xpg4/bin/sh` or `#! /bin/ksh`, as `/bin/sh` was not a POSIX shell back then but still on old SysV shell.